# Separate strings by specific sign in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this: `Test:11747:v:0:27500:4760:4720:407`
how can I put each of these sections of string (which split by ":") into a new string?
something like this: a = Test, b = 11747, etc.

Comment: You mean you want to *split* the string?

Comment: `"Test:11747:v:0:27500:4760:4720:407".split(":")` returns a list that contains the required strings. If you want to assign them to variables you can do: `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = "Test:11747:v:0:27500:4760:4720:407".split(":")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
"Test:11747:v:0:27500:4760:4720:407".split(":")
```

You will get a list of the splited string.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "Test:11747:v:0:27500:4760:4720:407"
b = a.split(':')
```

Here you have b as a list: ['Test', '11747', 'v', '0', '27500', '4760', '4720', '407']

Then you can loop it and make what ever you want.

```
for c in b:
    print(c)
```